# In Google Analytics, how is Average Page Load calculated for Virtual Page Views

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a full screen image gallery that is opened via js when a user interacts with an image on the page. When this occurs, we fire a GA Virtual Page view, which we can view in analytics.

I can see the impressions for this fine in GA but I also see an Average Page Load(secs). How is this calculated? I would assume on a standard page view that this is the time until the window.onload event fires, but I'm not sure what this time is measuring when a virtual page view is fired later.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related but rather about how Google Analytics works may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll ask there instead if thats the correct place for it, i didn't know it existing and nothing showed up in the search before I posted. I dont hold out much hope if I have to tho, as there are 15000 tagged with google-analytics here and 127 tagged with it in webapps :D